# CentOS 6.4 へ、Python3系をインストールしたいのですが、「yum」「make install」「ANACONDA」「PIP」？？？

Tags: python, centos

**環境**
・CentOS 6.4

**現状**
・Python 2.7.3インストール済
・ソースから自分でビルドしてインストール(sudo make install)
※インストールしただけで全く使用していない

**やりたいこと**
・Python3系インストール
・なるべく最新が良いが、3系だったら何でも良い

**今後**
・Python3系のみ使用予定
(もしかすると、Python 2.7.3も使用するかも。可能性は低いです)

---

**Q**
**・yumで最新版はインストール出来ない？**
・yumでインストール可能なPythonバージョンはどうやって確認するのでしょうか？

**[公式のpythonは入れなくていい](http://qiita.com/y__sama/items/5b62d31cb7e6ed50f02c)**
・どういう意味でしょうか？

**ANACONDA**
・オールインワンインストールは魅力的だけれども、余計な内容も含まれることになると思うのですが
・ライブラリを個別にたくさんインストールするのは面倒ということでしょうか？
・Pythonライブラリは個別インストールすると、依存関係の問題が発生する？

**PIP**
・ライブラリをインストールする際に使用？
・Python本体をインストール用途では使えない？

---

**その他**
・以前、ImageMagickをソースから自分でビルドしてインストールしたら、後でバージョン競合して、アンインストールするのがちょっとだけ面倒でした(yumでインストールしたバージョンはすぐにアンインストール出来たのですが)
・なので、なるべく後から管理しやすい方法でインストールしたいのですが……

Comment: [PyenvによるPython3.x環境構築](http://qiita.com/akito1986/items/be5dcd1a502aaf22010b)できますが、CentOS7を使う方がおすすめします。

Comment: 「CentOS7を使う方がおすすめします」。どういった理由からでしょうか？ OSアップデートは何となく怖いのですが、「PyenvによるPython3.x環境構築」と関係があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 個人的な意見ですが、Pythonはともかく、他の新バーションのプログラムやライブラリのインストールはいろいろ苦労になるんでしょう。OS自体アップデートしなくても、docker を利用して、新OSを使える方法もあるんです。

Comment: なるほど、仮想化を使いこなせるようになれば、環境構築に苦労しなくてもすむのかな、と思いました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

状況をあまり理解していませんが、CentOS を使っているのでしたら RPM でパッケージ管理をするのが正として述べます。OS のパッケージ管理システムを使って Python 3 をインストールした上で Python のパッケージ管理をどうするかを考えると良いと思いますが、まずは OS のパッケージ管理について書きます。

以前は EPEL という Fedora プロジェクトの拡張リポジトリを使うのが定番でしたが、今後はそれが Software Collections へ移行していくと思われます。Software Collections は RHEL が公式にサポートする拡張リポジトリです。名前が同じなのでややこしいのですが、その公式サポートの拡張リポジトリをコミュニティ主導でビルドして RHEL 以外でも利用できるようにもしています。

例えば、コミュニティ主導の Software Collections で CentOS 6 向けに Python 3.x 系が提供されています。

- https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/user/rhscl/?search=python3&policy=&repo=&order_by=-download_count&per_page=10

Python 3 系をインストールしたいだけであれば、この拡張リポジトリを使って環境を切り替えたりするのがシステムの環境を管理できる状態にしておくという意図でなるべく OS のパッケージ管理システムを使うのが良いと思います。

Comment: Python 3.5 ってyumでインストール出来るのですね。出来ないのかと思っていました…

Answer (score 4):

> ・yumで最新版はインストール出来ない？

t2y さんの回答のとおりです。

> [公式のpythonは入れなくていい](http://qiita.com/y__sama/items/5b62d31cb7e6ed50f02c)
>   ・どういう意味でしょうか？

この記事の内容は偏っていると感じます。
anaconda を使う事で環境構築を楽にできる場面があることは否定しませんが、データサイエンティストの領域以外について同じ事が言えるとは思いません。

万人にオススメの方法は存在しません。
Python公式のパッケージは、最もミニマルで、コントロールしやすく、多少手間のかかる方法だと思います。

> ANACONDA
>   ・オールインワンインストールは魅力的だけれども、余計な内容も含まれることになると思うのですが

はい。

> ・ライブラリを個別にたくさんインストールするのは面倒ということでしょうか？

データサイエンティストとしては、そうだと思います。
Anacondaはデータサイエンティストがよく使うパッケージを初めからインストールしてくれるので、パッケージ管理や依存関係に煩わされたくない、DISKに空き容量のたくさんある人に向いていそうです。

> ・Pythonライブラリは個別インストールすると、依存関係の問題が発生する？

いいえ。
pipでインストールすれば依存関係は自動的に解決してくれます。

> PIP
>   ・ライブラリをインストールする際に使用？

はい。

> ・Python本体をインストール用途では使えない？

使えません。

Comment: 「公式のpythonは入れなくていい」。当初、個人的な意見かと思ったのですが、ストック数が1000件を超えていたので、pythonとはそういうものかな、と思い質問しました。「データサイエンティストの領域以外について同じ事が言えるとは思いません」「Anacondaはデータサイエンティストがよく使うパッケージを初めからインストールしてくれる」。なるほど、基本的には「データサイエンティスト」へ向けた内容なのですね。参考になりました